# How do I parse JSON array in Spinner?

Tags: android, json, spinner

I have `json` file need to parse, but I don't know how to parse.

my `json` file like this :

```
[
  {"city":"Taipei", "area":["Songshan","Sinyi","Datong"]},
  {"city":"Kaohsiung", "area":["Yancheng","Gushan"]}
]
```

First I create a class :

```
 class AreaData{
   String cityName;
   ArrayList<String> areas;

   public AreaData(String cityName, ArrayList<String> areas){
      this.cityName = cityName;
      this.areas = areas;
   }

   public AreaData(JSONObject object) { //from mainActivity
       try {
             cityName = object.getString("city");
             areas = ????
```

in My mainActivity , read JSON file in assets/zipcode.json

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 parseJSON(sb.toString());
```

then

```
private void parseJSON(String json)

try {
      JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
      for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
        AreaData areas = new AreaData(object); //it's in class
        cityString[i] = areas.cityName;
     }
```

in Spinner

```
cityAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cityString);

SpinnerCity.setAdapter(cityAdapter);
```

but I have another spinner, it's for the area.

If I can parse area, I guess spinner area will be no question.
Thank you.

Comment: your json is not in correct format. `area` values must be in array

Comment: `"area":["Songshan","Sinyi","Datong"]` like this

Comment: @Ashish Kudale : Thank you , my mistakes. I will fix it .

Comment: @TzuyuLin got it or still, you have a problem?

Comment: @Hemant N. Karmur , Yes , I am still don't know how to parse area array.

Comment: did your problem get solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONArray array= new JSONArray(json);                                          
 for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
   JSONObject jsonobject = array.getJSONObject(i);
 String name = jsonobject.getString("city");
 JSONArray participants = jsonObject.getJSONArray("area")
  for (int i = 0; i < participants.length(); i++) {
    yourArrayList.add(participants.getString(i))
  }

}
```

Comment: how do I define yourArrayList ?

Comment: I know how to define yourArrayList :
ArrayList<String> areaString;
areaString = new ArrayList<>();
areaString.add(participants.getString(j));

Answer (score 0):

first of all import this library

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
```

then as per your response use below model

```
public class Example {

@SerializedName("city")
@Expose
private String city;
@SerializedName("area")
@Expose
private List<String> area = null;

public String getCity() {
return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
this.city = city;
}

public List<String> getArea() {
return area;
}

public void setArea(List<String> area) {
this.area = area;
}

}
```

then to convert your string response to model use below code

```
Example example = gson.fromJson(yourstringresponse, Example.class)
```

now you can use this for your uses.

Comment: Can you tell me more gson example ?

Comment: please visit below sites to learn more related to the json : https://abhiandroid.com/programming/json
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm
https://abhiandroid.com/programming/json